# openpyxl is exporting excel file with error

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file where the first four rows contain some header text and the actual dataset starts from row 4. I am trying to build a simple function that reads the excel file and outputs the same excel file after deleting the first 4 rows.

This is what my code looks like before I put it into a function.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

wb = load_workbook('FILEPATH/excel.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

ws = ws.delete_rows(0,4)

wb.save(r"FILEPATH/deleted_row.xlsx")
```

When I run the code it executes the file properly but when I try to open the excel file it give me errors and says that the file is corrupted. A point to note is that the excel file has some formatting on the rop rows. Is that what is causing some issues?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: This is what the errors look like and the file does not open.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In openpyxl, the first row should be 1, not 0. So, if you are looking to delete the first 4 rows, you should change the `delete_row()` from

`ws = ws.delete_rows(0,4)`

to

`ws = ws.delete_rows(1,4)`